# Why there are many database connection type?

Tags: database, connection-string

Dear all,
I am working with Databases and I am confusing with their connection-strings . There are many connection types and there are many connection-strings with different structures. Each of time I want to connect to Database, I come to http://connectionstrings.com/ and find the connection string (I can't remember all connection strings). It waste the time.

So, Could you tell me the reason why many connection types exist with each other? why don't we consolidate theme to ONE type?

Thanks,
Binh Nguyen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is probably that there are many different DBMS (Database Management Systems) out there (e.g. MySQL, MSSQL, etc.), each produced by a different company or organization with different style and ideas about the right way to do things.  Additionally, for each DBMS there may be one or more different drivers to choose from for connecting to them, depending on what language you're using and other factors.

If you want them all to be standardized, you're going to have to get all the creators of both DBMS and drivers to agree on a standard form, which is pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are many database vendors supplying many versions of many databases over many protocols, etc.

Choice is a good thing.